# Not able to add OrkTable in display window of RViz

Tags: rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to recognize an object using linemod method as described in [ORK tutorials](http://wg-perception.github.io/ork_tutorials/tutorial03/tutorial.html). As per the tutorial, I am suppose to add 'OrkObject' in display window of RViz. But when I try to add it, the 'OrkObject' option is not available. Kindly explain the steps to add it.

**Platfrom:**
Ubuntu 16.04,
ROS Kinetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/285693/not-able-to-add-orktable-in-display-window-of-rviz/) by [Nitin](https://answers.ros.org/users/34183/nitin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2018-03-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-18**:
Can you pease update your question to include a link to the tutorial that you're referring to? Anytime you're having trouble with a tutorial or any other source please include a link to it in the body of your question.

**Comment by [Nitin](https://answers.ros.org/users/34183/nitin/) on 2018-03-19**:
Thanks for the reply. The above issue is solved after installing "object_recognition_ros_visualization" package.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-03-19**:
To make this useful for future users who may also encounter this issue, can you please update your question with a link to the tutorial and perhaps put your solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The above issue is solved after installing "object_recognition_ros_visualization" package. The git path of the package is [here](http://github.com/wg-perception/object_recognition_ros_visualization).

---

Originally posted by [Nitin](https://answers.ros.org/users/34183/nitin/) with karma: 36 on 2018-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0